# Compiling a code with MonoDevelop

Tags: monodevelop

I don't understand how does MonoDevelop compile a code. Once the code is correct, we select "Build" and then "Run", and that should be all?
Thanks!

Comment: You select "Build" if you want to compile it.  "Run" if you want to both compile and run it.  (That is, if you intend to select "Run" then you don't need to select "Build" first.)  Is this not what's happening for you?

Comment: I've been trying this, but for some reason, no output is produced. All I get is: User assembly '/Users/ninakuklisova/Projects/Sunday/Sunday/bin/Debug/Sunday.exe' is missing. Debugger will now debug all code, not just user code. Cannot open assembly '/Users/ninakuklisova/Projects/Sunday/Sunday/bin/Debug/Sunday.exe': No such file or directory. And I can't find the exe file anywhere else. How do these things work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command-Return (on a Mac) will Run with Debugging.  That's what I use 99% of the time.  One easy keystroke.  The executable ends up in the /bin folder of your project folder.

Comment: And what happens afterwards? Do you get an exe file? Does the supposed output appear immediately? Thanks!

Comment: I'm writing an iOS app, so the iOS simulator opens up and executes the code.  Same idea with Android.  With Mono for Mac, the application window opens.  Either way, the executable always ends up in the /bin folder of your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I installed Xamarin, and everything works well, in the way you described it above. Thank you for your patience!